# Unable to get the value of form fields when using enctype=multipart/form-data : java servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, image-uploading

I have written this to upload an image in the specified folder and store the path in database, but when i click on **add** a blank page is displayed, I have already created all the folders in **webcontent**.I am using tomcat server:

My **upload.jsp** code looks something like this:

```
        <form action="Add" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>Book name:  <input type="text" name="bname" required/></p>
            <p>Price:<input type="text" name="bprice" required/></p>
            <p>Quantity:<input type="text" name="bqty" required/></p>
            <p>Image: <input type="file" name="file" required/></p>
            <p>Course: <select name="course">
            <option>course 1</option>
            <option>course 2</option> <!-- Some more options-->
            <input type="submit" value="Add" name="Submit"/></p>
        </form>
```

The **Add.java** servlet code is:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    String bname=request.getParameter("bname");
    String bprice=request.getParameter("bprice");
    String bqty=request.getParameter("bqty");
    String path="images";
    String file=request.getParameter("file");
    String course=request.getParameter("course");
    if(course.equals("course 1"))
    {
        path="images/folder1";
    }
    else if(course.equals("course 2"))
    {
        path="images/folder2";
    }
    else
    {
        path="images";
    }
    MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,path);
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("",user,pass);

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into product(bname,course,price,qty,path) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,bname);      
        ps.setString(2,course);
        ps.setString(3,bprice); 
        ps.setString(4,bqty);   
        ps.setString(5,path+file);

        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.print("<p>Product added!</p>");

    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("upload.jsp");
    rd.include(request, response);

}
```

I get NullPointer exception.
I read somewhere that instead of using
     request.getParameter()
I shoud use
     m.getParameter()

I did that and it worked, But that won't solve my problem because my code determines the path based on the value of **course** from the form.

And also I need to get the filename of the file uploaded, right now I am doing this like this:
    String file=request.getParameter("file");

I was trying some sample code and when I used m.getParameter() I managed to get values of all fields except file(I want that coz i want to store the img path in the DB).
When I don't use enctype=multipart/form-data everything works fine (I also get the filename) except the error that content is multipart(That's obvious I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ServletRequest#getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) works only for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (this encoding is used by default if you don't specify `enctype` attribute on your form). You can read more information about form content types [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4).

From the line

```
MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,path);
```

I am assuming you are using the [com.oreilly.servlet library](http://www.servlets.com/cos/).

In this case, using [`MultipartRequest#getParameter`](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) is a correct way to get the values of fields. In order to get the name of the uploaded file, you can use [`MultipartRequest#getFilesystemName`](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html#getFilesystemName%28java.lang.String%29).

> my code determines the path based on the value of course from the form

I am afraid that you won't be able to do this in a clear way with com.oreilly.servlet library. What you could do is move the file by yourself like this:

```
m.getFile("file").renameTo(new File("newPath"));
```

Alternatively, you can consider using some other library for dealing with multipart data, such as [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/).

Comment: m.getFile("file").renameTo(new File("newPath")); what is the **newPath** here?

Comment: It's what you are renaming/moving file to, for example `m.getFile("file").renameTo(new File("images/folder1/" + m.getFilesystemName("file")));`

Comment: but how do i move files to different folders for ex. all files of course 1 to folder 1 and files of course 2 to folder 2

Comment: You'd call `renameTo` after you constructed `MultipartRequest` object, so you will be able to access the value of your *course* field at this point using `m.getParameter`.

Comment: and do i need to mention the image file extension?

Answer (score 2):

You can get both the form fields and the file using `cos-multipart.jar`.

The following worked for me:

```
public class FileUploadHandler extends HttpServlet {
    private final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/home/mario/Downloads";

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //fix max file size 500 Mb
    int maxFileSize = 500000 * 1024;
    int maxMemSize = maxFileSize;

    //getting form fields (both text as well as file) (enctype=multipart/form-data)
    MultipartRequest mreq = new MultipartRequest(request, UPLOAD_DIRECTORY, maxFileSize);
    String uname = mreq.getParameter("username");  //give 'id' in html accordingly
    String dateofupload = mreq.getParameter("uploaddate"); 
    //System.out.println(uname);

    String NEW_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;

  //get actual file name here  //name field in html tag has to be given accordingly
    String uploadedfilename = mreq.getFilesystemName("file");

 //renaming & moving the file to new location
   File newfileloc = new File(NEW_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + "/" + uploadedfilename);
   Boolean uploadresult = mreq.getFile("file").renameTo(newfileloc);  //true if success
  }
}
```

This initially saves the file to a location and rename/move it to new location. I could have saved it at the desired location but to do that I need file name, which comes only with the servlet request. But to access `filename` we need to create 'Multipart' request object. I tried to create `two` such things, one to access fields and the other to save file. But, cos-multipart.jar has some bugs in handling this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [Apache commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html). It helps you handle these kinds of scenarios and handles most of the business logic for you.

When using Apache Commons FileUpload you can parse the request like this:

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
factory.setRepository(repository);

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

You can parse all the individual

```
// Process the uploaded items
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItem item = iter.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        processFormField(item);
    } else {
        processUploadedFile(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: do i need servlet 3.0 and tomcat 7 for this?

Comment: No you don't need tomcat 7 or servlet 3.0. I'm using it with Tomcat 6.

Comment: which packages do i need to import?

Comment: You should be able to use version 1.3.1. See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this way:


DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            factory.setSizeThreshold(MEMORY_THRESHOLD);
            factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
            upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE); // sets maximum size of request (include file + form data)
            String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;

            File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
            if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
                uploadDir.mkdir();
            }

            List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

            if (formItems != null && formItems.size() > 0) {
                for (FileItem item : formItems) {
                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
                        //file field
                    } else {
                        other form field
                    }
```

Comment: isn't it the apache commons file upload??

Comment: add commons-fileupload-1.3.jar

Comment: I am actually using com.orielly.servlet library

Comment: use commons-fileupload-1.3.jar